# Implement own in memory cache mechanism in spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, caching, in-memory-cache

I was asked to implement an in memory cache mechanism in my spring boot application.
My application is related to social media.
User can register and login
User can add friend
User can post status with privacy criteria public and private
User can view public post and private post of their friend post only
User can see the post which has more number of likes and they have access to.

How can I implement my own cache mechanism? I should design my own data structure to store cache.

Which api end points can I have cache features?

I'm new to spring.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't write your own caching solution. There are caching solutions out there, use those. Writing a proper caching solution is a difficult task, better use an existing and proven one.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials available: https://auth0.com/blog/spring-boot-caching-101/

Comment: I actually did it using spring cache but my interviewer asked me implement this by my own.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done it by creating concurrent hashmap and stored value in runtime and also made that hashmap object Threadsafe. which means only one thread can edit the value of hashmap

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Caffeine, which is an already built and tested in-memory cache for Java applications? You can find more information at:

- https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine
- https://www.baeldung.com/java-caching-caffeine
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-caffeine-cache

It is pretty simple to configure and use. You will save yourself hours of development.